# How to get previouse redux state on Back button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, browser-history, walmart-electrode

I have search page where there is a search bar and some search filters. User can filter data using filters. on every filter change I am calling an api which brings updated data I am also updating route path accordingly. But when user press back button I want to redirect user to previouse page with last results popluated. I don't want to hit the api call again to fetch the data. is there a way that redux mentains it's history which can be auto populated when user press back button.

Comment: Hi ahmed this might help you please follow the link https://redux.js.org/recipes/implementing-undo-history

Comment: Can you share your code ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use componentWillUnmount and reset your data on that function.

Comment: But how do i know that what was previouse data? because I am not mentaining history of previose data